# SetCookie with GET method

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I was struggling with the correct position to  setcookie() in my Wordpress site, and I finally made it work by placing it at the very first line of my `header.php`. But I need it to build the cookie with values gotten from the url of a specific page, that is not the home page. So, the first line of my `header.php` is:

`<?php setcookie( 'mycookie', $_GET["var1"]."/".$_GET["var2"]."/".$_GET["var3"], strtotime( '+5 years' ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, false);?>`

I was expecting that when I go to the `http://www.example.com/?var1=01&var2=02&var3=03`, the cookie would be set to have value "01/02/03" but it just receives the same value as in any other page, "//", like it is not seeing the variables gotten by `$_GET[]`.

Any idea about how could I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing with your code, I made a few changes to it in order to debug it a little easier.

I noticed you wrote down "COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN," as parameters, I don't know if you are using it literaly but try replacing them with "/" and ".example.com" to make the cookie available to your whole domain or restrict if necessary.
That made it work on my server running PHP 5.3.x.

Note the cookie is created on the first time the page is run, but is only available from the second time the page is loaded onwards.

The first time you load the page you should see something like:

Cookie was Saved
1
01
02
03
Cookie mycookie does not exist... yet

The second time it should be like:

Cookie was Saved
1
01
02
03
01/02/03

Hope I could help.

```
<?php
$cookieName = "mycookie";
$cookieIsSaved = setcookie( $cookieName,
        $_GET["var1"]."/".$_GET["var2"]."/".$_GET["var3"],
        strtotime( "+5 years" ),
        "/",
        ".example.com",
        false,
        false);

if ($cookieIsSaved) {
  echo "Cookie was Saved<br/>";
}
else
{
  echo "Cookie was not Saved<br/>";
}

echo $cookieIsSaved."<br/>";
echo($_GET["var1"]."<br/>");
echo($_GET["var2"]."<br/>");
echo($_GET["var3"]."<br/>");

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {
  print_r($_COOKIE[$cookieName])."<br/>";
}
else
{
  echo "Cookie $cookieName does not exist... yet";
}
?>
```

Comment: it was extremely helpful, thank you for being so didactic. I and many other newbies very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use the query_vars[] sub-array of the $wp_query object:

```
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['var1'])) {
    // modify the where/join/groupby similar to above examples
}
```

or simply the get_query_var() function.

Comment: Thank you so much, ywarnier, but it is not working either. When I send an `echo($_GET["var1"]) just after the setcookie, I see the correct value, so, it's there but not going into the setcookie. I got nothing from echo(get_query_var('var1')).